# serial port not responding

Tags: c, serial-port

I wrote a program that communicate with serial port, using termios, this program will read serial port in non-blocking mode and write response to serial port once it read data. If there is no data read from serial port, the program will do other thing, on next loop, the program read serial port again.

now the question is, after sometimes gone, maybe several minutes, or maybe several hours, the serial port don't respond to my program any more. Even I execute `echo 'HB\n' > /dev/ttyUSB0`(then the serial port should respond 'HACK'), it doesn't respond any more..

I even don't known when the serial port is 'dead', I don't have any clue.. it 'dead' untimed.

here is my configuration:

```
/// set local mode options 
//tminfo.c_lflag |= ICANON;                                                                       
tminfo.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ISIG);                                             

/// set control mode options                                                                   
tminfo.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);                                                               
tminfo.c_cflag |= HUPCL; 

// set hardware flow control 
tminfo.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;       

// set how many bits in a character                                                               
tminfo.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
tminfo.c_cflag |= CS8;      

// set parity mode (default to odd validation), this option (PARENB) will both enable input and output parity checking
tminfo.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; // we don't need prity checking now                                                                                                                                 

/// set input mode options  
// set input parity checking
tminfo.c_iflag &= ~INPCK; 
tminfo.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;                                                                                                                                                                

/// set output mode options                                                                                                                      
tminfo.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;                                                                


tminfo.c_cc[VMIN] = 1; 
tminfo.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;                                                                  

/// set line speed, defaults to 38400bps, both for input and output                           
// this call will set both input and output speed                                                 
cfsetspeed(&tminfo, B38400);
```

It's hard to debug the serial in this situation. I really can't figure out what cause the serial port 'dead' on earth. I'm nearly crazy...

what the possible reason? Any help will be appreciated!

#### update:

I have wrote some code to the other end of the serial port, when it receive 'HB', it will respond 'HACK'

Comment: When serial communications go wrong, the problem is often hard to debug without the right equipment. You should make sure it's your code at fault before debugging in vain: watch the serial port using `screen`, `minicom` or even just `stdbuf -I0 hexdump /dev/ttyS0 (or whatever your serial port is) and ensure you're receiving data properly. If that works, it's likely something in your code. But we'll need to see the rest of it.

Comment: @Alexios thanks for replay, when my program can not read data from serial port, then I would open two terminals, one execute `cat /dev/ttyUSB0` and the other one execute `echo 'HB\n' > /dev/ttyUSB0` repeatly, but `cat /dev/ttyUSB0` also print nothing.. PS: I have wrote some code to the other end of the serial port, when it receive 'HB', it will respond 'HACK'

Comment: @Alexios so, it seems that my program cause the serial port 'dead' within the scope of whole system? But how could this be? I have searched almost a week but still find no idea...

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic here, please ask on [so] instead. You'll need to provide more information. Include a **complete** program that reproduces the problem.